# How do I convert an iText Document into a javax.activation.DataSource?

Tags: java, stream, itext

Is it possible to convert an iText document variable into a `javax.activation.DataSource`? If not, is there a way I can convert an iText document into either an `InputStream` or an `OutputStream`?

Comment: can you tell us a little more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well typically its the other way round, you make a PDF from a datasource.

Anyway, here is an example where in I have converted the contents of the PDF into stream. You can change the stream type as per your need:

```
package com.quicklyjava;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;

public class JavaReadPDF {


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("c:/XML.pdf");
        String page1 = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(page1.getBytes());
        System.out.println(page1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```